# "[ WARN:0 ] `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback" Error when running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to run this OpenCV code to detect faces with my video camera. It's giving me this error whenever I run my code. The light on my video camera blinks but then shuts down with this error in the console box along with this one **cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'**

Here's the code

```
# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# To capture video from webcam.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# To use a video file as input
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.mp4')

while True:
    # Read the frame
    _, img = cap.read()

    # Convert to grayscale
    #THIS IS THE ERROR AREA
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

    # Draw the rectangle around each face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # Display
    cv2.imshow('img', img)

    # Stop if escape key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your script is not able to find the `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` file properly because of relative path. Try to give an absolute path and check.